# docker can't run scrapy-splash

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm want to scrape dynamic content with splash and scrapy .When i follow the documentation for installation in Linux 'https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/' 
I am not able to run the image with command:
`docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash`
I get the followig error :

```
python3: can't open file '/app/bin/splash': [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I don't know where to find that file to change the permissions for it .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you installed docker, did you add your user to docker group?
If not, add it using

```
usermod -aG docker <your-user-name>
```

and then run

```
docker run -it -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
```